# Android onCreateOptionsMenu is not displaying

Tags: java, android, android-menu

In my android activity, i removed the Action Bar by using this Theme

```
 <style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></style>
```

but my problem is “onCreateOptionsMenu” is not display, I tried this method to create 
that pls see

```
 private void getOverflowMenu()
    {

        try
            {
                ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(Home.this);
                Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
                if (menuKeyField != null)
                    {
                        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config , false);
                    }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

in this  “onCreateOptionsMenu” is not displaying. please help me

but it displaying in Samsung

**Because:** in Samsung mobile has its own hardware menu button, but not in nexus etc

please see the image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got the answer

in my **AndroidManifest.xml** i just removed this line

```
   android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have action bar and neither a menu button (on most devices) where do you want to display your menu??

The easiest way is to use `PopupMenu`. Add a button somewhere in your layout and on the click even add the `PopupMenu` (Dropdown menu). If you want to use it for devices starting Android 2.1 use a Support Library.

You have [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) the android documentation about PopupMenu.

From SDK Manager you can download and see the support library v7 sample which includes `PopupMenuHelper`.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!